# How me multiply state

Tags: reactjs

In the constructor, declare state s3 which will be equal to state s1 times s2. Display it on the page.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return { s1: props.a1 }, { s2: props.a2 }, { s3: props(s2 * s1) }
}
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` what is the issue which let you use this method? Also `s1,s2` is not variable names and the `return` does not look valid.

Comment: Make your question descriptive. Your topic is not clear itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constructor of your react component, as you suggested in the post.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       s1:props.a1,
       s2:props.a2,
       s3:0 //<---------let's initialize with 0
   };
   this.updateS3 = this.updateS3.bind(this);
}
```

Now if you want it to happen on some event then you can call a method and use the `setState()` method to update the state and subscribe to the changes:

```
updateS3(){
   this.setState({ s3: this.state.s1 * this.state.s2 });
}
```

you have to have this line somewhere in your template:

```
<div>
    { this.state.s3 }
</div>
```